# How to call overridden child methods in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to loop over multiple different child classes of a parent. Ideally I would like to save the child objects in a vector of smart pointers. The following outputs "Update idle" for every call to the method Update. I would like for the call to be the overridden variants of the method. What is the best way of solving this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void Update(){
        std::cout << "Update idle" << std::endl;
    }; 
};

class Foo1 : public Foo
{
public:
    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << "Update Foo1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << Bar() << std::endl;
    }

    std::string Bar(){
        return "Update Foo2";
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vec{
        std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo{}), 
        std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo1{}), 
        std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo2{})
    };

    for (auto &&ptr : vec)
    {
        ptr->Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it behave and what are you expecting?

Comment: We do not know what you expect.

Comment: The stdout for all three calls is "Update idle". I would like for each object to call its own method and be able to access own methods.

Comment: You create Foo objects copied from other Foo* objects.

Comment: @S.M. is that because of missing constructors? how would I adapt this code? Thank you

Comment: @DeerFreak no, it is because you are using `std::make_shared()` incorrectly to begin with.

Comment: `std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo1{})` doesn't create a `shared_ptr` that manages an object of type `Foo1`.   It creates a `shared_ptr` that that manages a `Foo`, and that `Foo` is initalised using the expression `Foo1{}`.    Use ` std::make_shared<Foo1>()` instead.   Then the object managed by the `shared_ptr` will actually be of type `Foo1`, and virtual function dispatch will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::make_shared<T>(args)` creates an new instance of `T`, passing `args` to `T`'s constructor, and then returns that instance in a `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

As such, your code is not dynamically creating any `Foo1` or `Foo2` object for the `vector` at all.  It is creating 3 dynamic `Foo` objects, all of which are copy-constructed from temporary `Foo`, `Foo1` and `Foo2` objects.

In other words:

`std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo{})` is equivalent to `new Foo(Foo{})`

`std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo1{})` is equivalent to `new Foo(Foo1{})`

`std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo2{})` is equivalent to `new Foo(Foo2{})`

You actually want the equivalent of `new Foo`, `new Foo1` and `new Foo2`, so use this instead:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> vec{
    std::make_shared<Foo>(), 
    std::make_shared<Foo1>(), 
    std::make_shared<Foo2>()
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2VKqC6)

Even though your `std::vector` holds `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` elements, but  `std::make_shared<Foo1>()` will return a `std::shared_ptr<Foo1>()` and `std::make_shared<Foo2>()` will return a `std::shared_ptr<Foo2>()`, this is OK because `std::shared_ptr<Foo1>` and `std::shared_ptr<Foo2>` are convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` by virtue of the fact that `Foo1` and `Foo` derive from `Foo`.